# my fetch request is rejected when trying to retrieve the html from the url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I'm trying to fetch the html code of several urls in my express app but I bump into this error:

```
reject(`new FetchError(request to ${request.url}` failed, reason: ${err.message}, 'system', err));

FetchError: request to https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/lorem-ipsum-case-wondering/ failed, reason: socket hang up
```

Here's where I'm trying to fetch the html:

```
async function getHTML(link) {
    const html = (await (await fetch(link)).text()); // html as text
    const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM(html);
    return dom
}
```

Here's where I imported jsdom: `const jsdom = require("jsdom"); // By the way, the package is installed so there's no error about it`

What should I do to solve this? (Just comment if info here is not enough)

Comment: You state "...trying to fetch the html code of several urls", you might be getting timed out and you can't really "fix" that... Are you fetching different pages from the same site?

Answer (score 0):

My fault, just forgot to put the code in the try catch block:

```
async function getHTML(link) {
    try {
        const html = (await (await fetch(link)).text()); // html as text
        const dom = new jsdom.JSDOM(html);
        return dom
    } catch {
        return null
    }
}
```

Comment: that will help to not crash the app, so that works

Comment: Well as far as I know, these blocks should always be used when fetching data from a url since there the return of a data from the internet is uncertain.